# How do I use a variable containing a string in brackets with regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
import re

content = "This is a [story] to be told"
tag = r'[story]'

print(re.compile(rf'{tag}').search(content))
```

this returns: `<re.Match object; span=(3, 4), match='s'>`

I am using the 'r' prefix in the variable and the 'rf' prefix in the regex. Where am I going wrong? It keeps interpreting my variable as a coded string.

In my actual scenario I have a list of tags: `[r'[TAG1]', r'[TAG2]', r'[TAG3]']`
which I want to iterate over. I have solved the problem by escaping with '\' in every tag's string assignment but this makes the tags unusable when referencing them later, as 1 of the '\'s is not in the beginning or end of string (since strings are immutable).

I could try using slices but that seems incredibly inefficient. Is there a regex solution?

Comment: `r` does nothing here. You need `rf'{re.escape(tag)}'`. However, it does not make sense  if you just check for fixed values in a string, use `if tag in content`

Comment: solved. Thanks, overlooked the article.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I appreciate the addition. In my case however I also need the span